# Navigation bar space between li

Tags: html, css, navigation

Between the first list item and the second there seems to be a small space. How can I remove it? There is no spacing between the rest of the list items. Any idea how I can get rid of that spacing because it makes it look really bad.

```
.media {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
}

.media a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.media ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.media li:hover {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;

}

.media li {
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

And here is the div:

```
<div class="media">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <ul><li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that additional <ul> before the second item.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have a `ul` starting in between them [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efyddneb/)

```css
.media {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
}

.media a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.media ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.media li:hover {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;

}

.media li {
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the ul from in between li.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML includes a stray `<ul>` at the start of one of your `<li>`s.

Simply remove it

```
<div class="media">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a css

.media>ul>ul {
padding-top: 0;
}

```css
 .media {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px 3px #333333;
}

.media a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.media ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.media li:hover {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;

}

.media li {
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.media>ul>ul {
padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <ul><li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 ways to do this.
You can remove  from index link
OR
use "margin" in your css code like {margin:-5px;} .